# How to get Posts from all over the facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing a sentiment analysis software for a project, We tried to get post from Facebook but we need to specify the page from which we get the post unlike twitter which gives all the tweets. Can anyone guide us how to get post from all over the Facebook and if we need to subscribe Graph API for such privilege.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Public Feed API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

...but it restricted, and you cannot apply.

As of now, there is no way search for public posts.